# Embeddable Workflow Engine

Tags: python, node.js, workflow, process-control

I am using a number of Notification Delivery Providers, such as Twilio, SendGrid, etc. to send Emails, SMSs, Push Notifications, etc.

I am aiming to develop a notification dispatcher service which allows us to configure different workflows based on the notification type.

For example, for Emails:
Send an email to Sendgrid
If it fails, retry using exponential backoff.
If email still fails to send for a known reason, mark as attempt as failed and switch to another provider (X), trigger new workflow.

My understanding of Apache Airflow is that it is more suited to ETL type processes. In my case, I expect my Email workflow to run 25+ times a second. The API is also unstable/ experimental.

My primary technology is NodeJS. Prefer something that allows me to define a workflow and execute NodeJS tasks via REST API.